# how to get the form textboxes and image values form type enctype="multipart/form-data" in java

Tags: java, forms, file-upload, multipartform-data

how to get the form values in the servlet while it is encripted as multipart/form-data.

```
<FORM name="filesForm" action="FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="file" name="filename">
</form>
```

how to get these values in the servlet firstname,lastname and file values.

Comment: I guess there are duplicates of this question on SO. Let me find some :)

Comment: Ok here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857626/unable-to-read-form-field-in-servlet Read it, might be helpful to you.

Comment: And another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551431/upload-image-from-android-to-java-servlet-and-save-it. HttpServletRequest.getPart() is what you need, this handles multipart requests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use apache commons fileupload: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Generally your code will look something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
```

...

```
DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request); // request is HttpServletRequest

// iterate through form fields
for(FileItem item:items) {
    if(item.isFormField()) { // text fields, etc...
        String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
        String value = item.getString();
    } else { // file fields
        item.write(new File("some/path"));
    }
}
```