# Text field and fileupload in one form

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to create a form with two textfields and one fileupload. How can I handle the textfields in my Servlet? It doesn't work with `request.getParameter("user")`.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="text" name="user" id="user"/></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></p>
    <p><input type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Senden"/></p>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

While your form is declared as `multipart/form-data` then you need to check if the stream contains form field type or a multipart type.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Unable to read form field in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857626/unable-to-read-form-field-in-servlet) should help answer your question.  In essence you need to create a new MultipartRequest object using the request as an argument and then call getParameter on that object.  Like this:

```
String dir = directoryToSaveFileTo;
MultipartRequest r =new MultipartRequest(request, dir);
String User = r.getgetParameter("user");
```